# Automatic logging of scripts executed by users

Tags: shell-script, logs, audit

That's a recurrent question of my workmates. We are a team of many people which works in the same Unix and Linux servers. The recurrent questions is if there are a log or something similar by default in the linux/unix OS where see when a user launch a sh/ksh script or any other executable program in the server.

For example, Susan executes `write.ksh` at 10h23, Paul executes `files_rights.sh` at 11h03 and Yves executes `./rename_files` at 13h12. The sysadmin is on holidays but he will arrive tomorrow and want to see who execute what and when he/she did it.

Comment: You might be able to use sudo to use this. Restrict privileges to only certain groups for running the script, and then force the use of sudo to get those privileges. Usage of sudo is automatically logged.

Comment: @FaheemMitha But then any actions carried out without `sudo` will not be logged. I haven't done anything like this before, but I know that such tools exist. They're called "system auditing tools".

Comment: @JosephR. True. But I think (like I said) that it is possible to force the use of sudo. However, there might be better tools for this.

Answer (score 4):

If you have audit logging enabled (`auditd`) you should be able to query the audit.log file to see when so and so ran command X.

#### Example

```
$ sudo ausearch -x /usr/bin/sudo | head -5
----
time->Sat Dec  7 21:15:15 2013
type=USER_AUTH msg=audit(1386468915.558:419): pid=2189 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=1 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:authentication acct="saml" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
----
time->Sat Dec  7 21:15:15 2013
```

Be aware though that you'll have to develop rules that will monitor either specific executables or entire directories of files. But `auditd` is the software that can report very fine grain details as to what applications and file objects are being used on a given Linux box.

#### References

- [Chapter 32. Introducing an Audit Rule Set](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.scenarios.html)